# convert datetime to date in c#.Net but not a string date

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading Datetime value From Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538321/reading-datetime-value-from-excel-sheet)

I want to compare a date (e.g. 18/10/2012 00:00:00) with an Excel date. If I am using datetime.toshortdatestring() the value gets converted to string and comparing a string with an Excel date doesnot work. Can you please suggest me some other workaround to this problem.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "an Excel date". What *type of value* do you have?

Comment: Can you please be more clear?

Comment: @Jodrell, I would say that's exactly what the OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

Would the `DateTime.Date` property work for you?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx