# Read DateTime from Excel using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, format, epplus

I wrote data into an Excel File using EPPlus.

I have a column with the type date formatted like this

```
ws.Column(1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd h:mm";
```

In the file, it is saved correctly.

But when I try to read it using `ws.Cells[1, 1].Value.`, it prints it 41500.678634259297

Comment: It's all covered in this SO question: [Reading Datetime value From Excel sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538321/reading-datetime-value-from-excel-sheet) Hope it helps, but if you need more help just ask

Comment: That you're using epplus shouldn't make a difference to this