# How to properly read a single Excel cell

Tags: vb.net, excel

I've been looking up in Google in these past days but I still can't find a good answer to this one.

Currently, this is how I do it:

```
For Each cell In ws.Range(fromCol, toCol)
    If IsNothing(cell.Value) Then Exit For

    valueList.Push(cell.Value.ToString())
Next
```

But when it reads a `cell` whose assumed data type is Time, it returns a Double value. I try to parse that value but it's not the same as expected.

How can I properly read a single Excel `cell` with an assumed type of Time?

Comment: Have you read this SO post?: [What is the difference between .text, .value, and .value2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359835/what-is-the-difference-between-text-value-and-value2)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Thanks for the link but in my case, `Value` and `Value2` returns the same result for that cell I'm talking about. However, according to the top answers in that link, Text` is bad but I think I'm going for it as I can't see any flaw as of now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading Datetime value From Excel sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538321/reading-datetime-value-from-excel-sheet)

Comment: @mr5 Did you try `DateTime.FromOADate` as suggested in the link above?

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment suggesting the article,

`.Text` is a bad idea in the sense that it will give you just the displayed string in that cell. If you use `TypeName` on the cell's content, for example, it will always return string regardless of any datatypes the content might be. However, if you use `.Value`, it will return the actual datatype name of the content of that cell.

This can prove useful to you if you're using `TypeName` in a comparison for instance. It saves you using conversion functions.

Take this example:

```
Sub Test()
Range("A1") = "True"
Debug.print(TypeName(Range("A1").Value))
Debug.print(TypeName(Range("A1").Text))
End Sub
```

This Output is:

```
Boolean
String
```