# Date format changing while converting from excel to datatable in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tried to import the excel the date column in excel is changing to number format. 
For example
I have 3 column in the excel
Name,age and Dob

When I try to convert this excel into the datatable the date in the Dob column is changing to a number.

```
using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fi))      
{
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[sheetName];
    ExcelCellAddress startCell = worksheet.Dimension.Start;
    ExcelCellAddress endCell = worksheet.Dimension.End;
    if (endCell.Row > 0)
    {
        for (int col = startCell.Column; col <= endCell.Column; col++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[startCell.Row, col].Value));
        }

        for (int row = startCell.Row + 1; row <= endCell.Row; row++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            int x = 0;
            for (int col = startCell.Column; col <= endCell.Column; col++)enter code here
            {
                dr[x++] = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value;
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: provide the format in excel and the format you got in datatable.

Comment: In excel the format is MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: what you got in DataTable?

Comment: For example : 7/1/2016
The above date while converting to datatable i am getting number  42552

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Datetime value From Excel sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538321/reading-datetime-value-from-excel-sheet)

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
double val= double.Parse("42552");
DateTime requiredDate= DateTime.FromOADate(val);
```

Comment: This answer is helpful for me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try to this, by changing the format of the Cells.

```
Range r = (Excel.Range)worksheetobject.Cells[row,column];
r.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY";
```

**AND** can do this also,

```
double value = double.Parse(convertedNumber);
DateTime yourData = DateTime.FromOADate(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the column type to "Text" and set the format:

```
worksheet.Cells[row, col].NumberFormat = "@";
```