# How to import DateTime cell from Excel in C# properly

Tags: c#, excel, datetime

I am trying to import Excel file's data into my ERP with a custom C# application. But, I am having a problem with Date type cells. Depends on the regional settings of computers, Date type cells cannot be converted to DateTime in C#, I am always having a problem with this Date from Excels when users use different computers.

If computer's regional settings is U.S.

```
11-25-2016
```

If computer's regional settings is Turkish

```
25-11-2016
```

How can I do the proper conversion?

Comment: How are you reading the Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureinfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date, cultureinfo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the date to C# using the following code:

```
DateTime conv = DateTime.FromOADate(excelDate);
```

Refer this answer: [Reading Datetime value From Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538321/reading-datetime-value-from-excel-sheet)