# Datatype for 1:00 ( number of Hours) in c#

Tags: c#, excel, time, timespan

I have column in Excel which has the number of hours in Time Format. 
For example-  2:00, 3:00
My job is to get those numbers from excel and put them into SQL.
so what is the data type that I need to used to get those values in c# code. 
I have tried a couple of ways! It says - "Cannot convert Double to string" or "Cannot convert Double to TimeSpan"
Please let me know what do I need to do.

Thanks

Comment: Well a C# `double` in SQL is a `float`. Is that what you mean? It would be helpful if you showed one of the ways you've tried already.

Comment: If its a *count* of hours as opposed to a time, convert to minutes and use int in C#/SQL Server

Comment: @Equalsk No. I am trying to pull that value from EXCEL to a c# code. While pulling it, What is the data type that I need to mention to pull it successfully?
I have tried: double hours;

Comment: @Equalsk No. I am trying to pull that value from EXCEL to a c# code. While pulling it, What is the data type that I need to mention to pull it successfully?
I have tried: 
double hours;
hours = (double)(range.Cells[i, 26] as Excel.Range).Value;

Comment: Well since you don't show how you pull it (Interop? OpenXML? OLEDB?) then nobody can give you a proper answer. Show the way you've tried already, or at least be a bit more specific about how you're getting this from Excel...

Comment: @AlexK. I have tried it. It says "Cannot Convert Double to INT" :(

Comment: @Equalsk I am sorry, using Interop

Comment: Please edit code into the question, not a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading Datetime value From Excel sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538321/reading-datetime-value-from-excel-sheet)

Comment: @Equalsk 
double d = double.Parse(b);
DateTime conv = DateTime.FromOADate(d);
if this is the answer. Please let me know what could be the 'b' in it?
I tried to do this: 
double.Parse((string)(range.Cells[i, 26] as Excel.Range).Value2);
it says, cannot convert double to string.

Comment: There's a perfectly good example in that thread with the bold title saying **Reading Datetime value From Excel sheet**.

Comment: @Equalsk That is completely changing the format to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Excel only uses effectively 2 data types when data is read from C# - numbers and strings.  Dates are usually passed as numbers which represent a number of days (including fractional days to represent time) since 1/1/1900, and can easily be converted to `DateTime` using the [`FromOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx) method.  You can then use the [`TimeOfDay` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx) to get just the time as a `TimeSpan` object, which has a `TotalHours` property that represents the number of hours (and fractional hours) the time span represents.

Another method would be to take the fractional part of the number and multiply it by 24.

Comment: Appreciate you reply, It's not a Date, It's just a number of Hours
1:00 it means one hour. It doesn't mean 1:00 AM or PM.