# I need help understanding this date format

Tags: date, datetime, iso

I have a csv file with a date column and I am having trouble trying to figure out the format in which this date is in.

[image]

I have tried several timestamp converters and none of them seem to give me the accurate date.

The dates should all range within 2017.

Comment: `DateTime.FromOADate(42954.49986111111);` -> 2017-08-07T11:59:48.0000000. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538321/reading-datetime-value-from-excel-sheet for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel store dates and times as a floating point number as days since 1900/01/01 00:00:00. So 42954.49986111111 represents 2017-08-07 11:59:48.0000000.

.Net can already understand this "format":

```
DateTime.FromOADate(42954.49986111111);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is days from 1900, so to get timestamp you should add this value to 1900/01/01 timestamp multiplying on 1000 * 24 * 60 * 60

It should work

```
const d = Date.UTC(1900, 1, 1) + 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 42982
console.log(new Date(d).toString())
```

Comment: Or just `DateTime.FromOADate()`

Comment: @phuzi I didnt know this method, of course it is shorter

Comment: Beware that this method will not work for dates before 30th December 1899. The OA date number represents days for the integer part and fractional part of a day for the decimal part. i.e 3.5 would be 3 days and 12 hours after 30th December 1899. When applied to negative numbers the negative only applies to the integer part. So -2.5 means 2 days before 30th December 1899 plus half a day, meaning it's only 1.5 days earlier not 2.5 days.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is any date formate.

```
moment(42954.4998611111).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
"January 1st 1970, 5:30:42 am"
```

Comment: Not even close to being correct! How is this the accepted answer. This will translate as seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00

Comment: 42954.4998611111 it is any date or not?

Comment: When u will click on any cell u will find exect data on top left corner.

Comment: Nope, Excel uses days since 1900-01-01 [How Excel Stores Dates](https://www.exceltactics.com/definitive-guide-using-dates-times-excel/#How-Excel-Stores-Dates)